# angular.js how to mock(or stub) xhr request in each test

Tags: angularjs

In angular js unit test, I wanted to set xhr response to each test(in "it" method"), not in beforeEach method, but it seems not working.?

This works

```
describe('ExampleListCtrl', function(){
  var $scope, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.expectGET('examples').respond([]);   // <--- THIS ONE
    $controller(ExampleListCtrl, {$scope: $scope = $rootScope.$new()});
  }));

  it('should create "examples"  with 0 example fetched', function() {
    expect($scope.examples).toBeUndefined();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect($scope.examples).toEqual([]);
  });

});
```

result

```
Executed 8 of 8 SUCCESS (0.366 secs / 0.043 secs)
```

But this fails with error when I move expectGet method to each method. I don't know why.

```
describe('ExampleListCtrl', function(){
  var $scope, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $controller(ExampleListCtrl, {$scope: $scope = $rootScope.$new()});
  }));

  it('should create "examples"  with 0 example fetched', function() {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('examples').respond([]);  // <--- MOVED TO HERE
    expect($scope.examples).toBeUndefined();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect($scope.examples).toEqual([]);
  });
});
```

Here is the error

```
....
at /Users/me/app/test/unit/controllers/ExampleListCtrlSpec.js:3:1
      Error: No pending request to flush
at Error (<anonymous>)
at Function.$httpBackend.flush (/Users/me/app/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:1171:34)
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/me/app/test/unit/controllers/ExampleListCtrlSpec.js:14:18)
```

---- Edited ----

Following the advice below, I have moved the controller out of beforeEach, and changed test like this, so that I can test $httpBackend.expectGET more than once.

```
describe('ExampleListCtrl', function(){
  var $scope, $rootScope, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    controller = $controller;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  it('should create "examples" model with 0 example fetched from xhr', function() {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('examples').respond([]);
    controller(ExampleListCtrl, {$scope: $scope});
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect($scope.examples).toEqual([]);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because once you instantiate your controller, it fetches `$http` and, thus, `$httBackend`. So, all expectations shall be made prior to requiring it.

If you wish to move your `$httpBackend.expectGet` to the spec (`it` block) then you need to move your `$controller(ExempleListCtrl, ...` as well, after the expectations.

Comment: @bighostkim there are issues with making these request on controller load, think about abstracting out to $rootScope and initializing on app.run(). but your tests is failing because of what Caio pointed out.

Comment: And if you follow @Lucas approach, then you can move only your expectations to the spec, as you require, before calling this method that would issue the `$http` request. @Lucas, I'm curious, which issues are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about making the get requests each time the controller is loaded (e.g navigating between two controllers/pages) which in turn refreshes the data. To me I thought this was bad UX. By moving the request up to the rootScope the request is only made once at app start so the data isn't refreshed when navigating between controllers.

Comment: @Lucas, good point. I agree it is bad approach to run $http when controller is initialized.

Comment: I've changed my mind again on when to load data... take a look at http://www.egghead.io/video/Kr1qZ8Ik9G8 and other 'Resolve' related videos to understand the best practices for loading controller data