# Testing repsonse of angular service with $http get

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

Im pretty new to AngularJS and testing so im trying to test my service i made in AngularJS.

I have set up the service like this

```
var serviceModule = angular.module('App.services', []);
serviceModule.factory('subscribeService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getNumberOfSubscribers : function() {
            return $http.get('/jsonFiles/subscribers.json')
                .then(function(subscribers) {
                     return subscribers.length;
                });
        }
    };
});
```

And the test goes like this.

```
describe('Subscribe service test', function() {
var httpBackend,
    subscribeServiceMock, 
    subscribers;

subscribers = [{"email": "test1@mail.com", "subscriptions": "A,B,C"},
               {"email": "test2@mail.com", "subscriptions": "A,C,D"},
               {"email": "test3@mail.com", "subscriptions": "B,C,F"}];

beforeEach(module('App.services'));     

beforeEach(inject(function(subscribeService){
    subscribeServiceMock = subscribeService;
}));

it('Should return total numbers of subsribers', inject(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/jsonFiles/subscribers.json').respond(subscribers);
    var numberOfSubscribers = subscribeServiceMock.getNumberOfSubscribers();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(numberOfSubscribers).toEqual(3);

}));
```

The test seams to fail with this error: 
"Subscribe service test Should return total numbers of subsribers FAILED"
" Expected { then : Function } to equal 3"

Im wondering where i have got this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to inject your httpBackend? Try this on your "beforeEach" call:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(subscribeService, _$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_){
    subscribeServiceMock = subscribeService;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_('MyCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
}));
```

**UPDATE**

As I found out here: [AngularJS Issues mocking httpGET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766051/angularjs-issues-mocking-httpget-request)

It seems there's in fact a difference between these two "injection methods"

Comment: Is there any difference to injecting it beforeEach or in the test it self?

Comment: The only difference is that beforeEach is called once for every "it" clause you have on your test... If you have like 6 test cases, you could write once at beforeEach and have it run for all of them

Comment: But im already injecting httpBackend in the test. Shouldn't be any difference

Comment: You're right, it won't make any difference. It seems I wasn't paying proper attention when I first read your question, sorry.

See if this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766051/angularjs-issues-mocking-httpget-request