# Unsatisfied Request in $httBackend in AngularJs Jasmine testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

```
    // Devices call
    httpBackend.expect('GET', '/v1/devices/machine/22')
        .respond(200,mock_Device);

    //DevicesConfig call
    httpBackend.expect('GET', '/v2/devices/config/19442')
        .respond(200,mock_Devices_Config);

    //LatestDevices call
    httpBackend.expect('GET', '/v1/devices/latest/19442')
        .respond(200,mock_Devices_Latest);

    //Machinehistory call
    httpBackend.expect('GET', '/v1/devices/history/19442/5')
        .respond(200,mock_Machine_History);

it('It should fetch all machines details', function() {
    httpBackend.flush();
    scope.getMachines(); --Controller Call
```

}

In controller i will make a call for service which is in promise.All the calls are passed except machinehistory call which is getting

**Error: Unsatisfied requests:**

Please help me to sort out this error.

Comment: The Get url , exist? Try it in web browser

Comment: yes its working fine

Comment: if the promises is resolved the data then the url will get unsatisfied request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Issues mocking httpGET request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766051/angularjs-issues-mocking-httpget-request)